# PHP odbc_result() appears to be returning random uninitialized memory for varchar fields in 5.5+; identical code working in 5.4

Tags: php, character-encoding, odbc

I'm using an ODBC connection to retrieve data on a Windows Server. After upgrading PHP from 5.4 to 5.6 (as well as on 5.5) all varchar fields seem to be returning random uninitialized memory, although the string length does match that of the field being queried.

For example, a query returning the string "Test.txt" in 5.4 returns the following in 5.5+:

[image: garbled]

I've compared my `php.ini` settings between the two versions and they seem to be identical in terms of what's being specific related to charsets and ODBC settings.

I can run both versions side by side on the same ODBC resource at the same time and get these results. Non-varchar fields like dates and integers are printing correctly. I'm simply running the x86 thread safe `php.exe` executable downloaded from http://windows.php.net/download for 5.4, 5.5, and 5.6.

What else can I configure to try and resolve this?

**Edit:** I'm using the Unified ODBC functions like so:

```
$o = odbc_connect("Driver=MMODBC;Server=localhost;Database=odbc_mapping;", [user], [pass]);
$r = odbc_exec($o, "SELECT * FROM Table");
while (odbc_fetch_row($r)) {
    print odbc_result($r, 1);
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code with which you connect to your database, including connection string (except password), and whether you use `PDO`, `mysqli_` functions or (god forbid) `mysql_` functions

Comment: Connection string posted. I'm simply using the Unified ODBC functions.

Comment: `var_dump(bin2hex($theString))` to see whether there's any difference in the data received from the database, or merely in how it's interpreted after that.

Comment: Great idea! Here's the same string in both versions. 5.4: `string(30) "5a3a5c5465737420666f6c6465725c"`. 
5.6: `string(30) "00da24017200df0019000000110000"`

Comment: That's... quite different. All those `NUL` bytes in there are rather disturbing. 

Comment: Right? It's so strange. Same system, downloaded both php versions and running them side by side in cli. Stock php.ini in both with one or two identical changes applied (uncommented mysqli module, set timezone, etc).

Comment: @deceze I've updated my question after realizing that the output is different on each run. The differences are subtle which is why I didn't notice them, and only thought the output was changing when I was tinkering with encoding settings and re-running.

Comment: @CharlieS, can you write which server you are trying to connect to? I couldn't understand if it is mssql, mysql, or some db file (xls/mdb file).

Comment: @Dekel it's an older proprietary piece of Windows software that has an ODBC driver.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a handful of bugs at http://bugs.php.net related to uninitialized data appearing in odbc function results. They are primarily for older (e.g. 5.3) versions of php. That appears to be what's happening in this case, or some variant therein.

**Switching to PDO in 5.6 has completely resolved the issue for me.**

Comment: Thanks for the upvotes – I lost 100 due to bounty :)